# Consulta Simples Nacional Optantes (por CNPJ)

Tags: php, libcurl, web-crawler, captcha

Estou tentando implementar uma consulta do [Simples Nacional](http://www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br/SimplesNacional/Aplicacoes/ATBHE/ConsultaOptantes.app/ConsultarOpcao.aspx), o funcionamento é parecido com a consulta por CNPJ da receita.

Detalhes que percebi até o momento:

1. Após carregar a página, executa um `ajax` (**arquivo** `captcha2.js`) que retorna 3 itens em formato `JSON {Token, Dados, ContentType}`. O `Token` é armazenado em um *cookie* que provavelmente serviria para validar a imagem após submit. `Dados` é o *base64* da imagem. `ContentType` o tipo da imagem.
2. Ele gera o input do cnpj concatenando um número que também é armazenado em outro input hidden (**id**: `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_HiddenField1`).
3. Existem outros inputs (__VIEWSTATE, __EVENTVALIDATION, __EVENTARGUMENT, __EVENTTARGET) que armazenam valores, os últimos dois, geralmente vazios...

Estou capturando os dados iniciais e setando os headers na segunda requisição para recuperar os dados, porém, o problema é que sempre dá erro (*Caracteres anti-robô inválidos. Tente novamente.*).

Seguem os códigos que tenho até agora (podem estar bagunçados ou com linhas desnecessárias, são apenas testes ainda, falta limpar o código posteriormente):

**ConsultaCnpjSimplesNacional.php:**

```
class ConsultaCnpjSimplesNacional
{

    /**
     * Devolve um array de parâmetros para consulta de CNPJ Simples Nacional
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getParams()
    {
        $ckfile = tempnam("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");

//        ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_depth', 5);
//        ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_children', 256);
//        ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_data', 10000000000000);

        $urlConsulta = 'http://www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br/SimplesNacional/Aplicacoes/ATBHE/ConsultaOptantes.app/ConsultarOpcao.aspx';
        $chInicial = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($chInicial, CURLOPT_URL, $urlConsulta);
        curl_setopt($chInicial, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($chInicial, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($chInicial, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($chInicial, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($chInicial, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
        curl_setopt($chInicial, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
        curl_setopt($chInicial, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20000);
        curl_setopt($chInicial, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20000);
        $response = curl_exec($chInicial);

        require_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'simple_html_dom.php';

        $html = str_get_html($response);
        $inputViewStateValue = $html->getElementById('__VIEWSTATE')->value;
        $inputEventValidationValue = $html->getElementById('__EVENTVALIDATION')->value;
        $inputHiddenField1Value = $html->getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_HiddenField1')->value;
        $inputHddServidorCaptchaValue = $html->getElementById('hddServidorCaptcha')->value;
        $urlCaptchaContainer = $html->getElementById('captcha-container')->{'data-url'};
        $html->clear();
        unset($html);

        //Essa url informada, é definida no javascript captcha2.js
        //$chInicial = curl_init($urlCaptchaContainer . '/Captcha/Inicializa.ashx');
        curl_setopt($chInicial, CURLOPT_URL, $urlCaptchaContainer. '/Captcha/Inicializa.ashx');
        curl_setopt($chInicial, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($chInicial, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($chInicial, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($chInicial, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($chInicial, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
        curl_setopt($chInicial, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
        curl_setopt($chInicial, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded']);
        $response = curl_exec($chInicial);
        $header_size = curl_getinfo($chInicial, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
        $response = substr($response, $header_size);
        curl_close($chInicial);
        $jsonResponse = json_decode($response);

        $browser = new Browser();
        if ($browser->getBrowser() == Browser::BROWSER_IE /*&& $browser->getVersion() <= 8*/) {
            $randomName = utf8_encode(\Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString());
            $pasta = Url::to("@webroot/assets/temp_images_ie/$randomName.png");
            $imgReturn = Url::to("@web/assets/temp_images_ie/$randomName.png");
            file_put_contents("$pasta", $jsonResponse->Dados);
        } else {
            $imgReturn = 'data:image/png;base64,' . $jsonResponse->Dados;
        }

        return [
            'cookie' => 'captcha_token=' . $jsonResponse->Token,
            'viewState' => $inputViewStateValue,
            'eventValidation' => $inputEventValidationValue,
            'hiddenField1' => $inputHiddenField1Value,
            'hddServidorCaptcha' => $inputHddServidorCaptchaValue,
            'captchaBase64' => $imgReturn
        ];
    }

    public static function consulta($cnpj, $captcha, $stringCookie, $viewState, $eventValidation, $hiddenField, $servidorCaptcha)
    {
        $result = [];
        $ch = curl_init('http://www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br/SimplesNacional/Aplicacoes/ATBHE/ConsultaOptantes.app/ConsultarOpcao.aspx');
        $ckfile = tempnam("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");

        $options = [
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
                'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
                'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate',
                'Accept-Language' => 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
                'Connection' => 'keep-alive',
                'Content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Cookie' => $stringCookie,
                'DNT' => 1,
                'Host' => 'www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br',
                'Origin' => 'http://www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br',
                'Referer' => 'http://www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br/SimplesNacional/Aplicacoes/ATBHE/ConsultaOptantes.app/ConsultarOpcao.aspx',
                'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.93 Safari/537.36'
            ],
            CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $ckfile,
            CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $ckfile,
            CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
                '__EVENTTARGET' => null,
                '__EVENTARGUMENT' => null,
                '__VIEWSTATE' => $viewState,
                '__EVENTVALIDATION' => $eventValidation,
                "ctl00\$ContentPlaceHolderConteudo\$$hiddenField" => $cnpj,
                'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderConteudo$HiddenField1' => $hiddenField,
                'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderConteudo$hddServidorCaptcha' => $servidorCaptcha,
                'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderConteudo$txtTexto_captcha_serpro_gov_br' => $captcha,
                'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderConteudo$btnConfirmar' => 'Consultar'
            ],
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 20000,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 20000
        ];
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        require_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'simple_html_dom.php';

        echo $response;
        exit();

        $html = str_get_html($response);

    }

}
```

**consulta_cnpj_simples.php**

```
/**
 * @var yii\web\View $this
 */
$this->title = 'Consulta CNPJ Simples Nacional';
try {
    $params = \app\common\components\consulta\ConsultaCnpjSimplesNacional::getParams();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    return Json::encode(['error' => 'error', 'mensagem' => $e->getMessage()]);
}
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => 'form-consulta-cnpj',
        'enableClientScript' => false,
        'action' => Url::to(['consulta/processa-cnpj-simples'], true),
        'method' => 'POST'
    ]
);
?>
<img id="image_captcha" class="img-thumbnail" src="<?= $params['captchaBase64'] ?>"/><br/><br/>
<input type="hidden" id="cookie" name="cookie" value="<?= $params['cookie'] ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="viewState" name="viewState" value="<?= $params['viewState'] ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="eventValidation" name="eventValidation" value="<?= $params['eventValidation'] ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenField1" name="hiddenField1" value="<?= $params['hiddenField1'] ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="hddServidorCaptcha" name="hddServidorCaptcha" value="<?= $params['hddServidorCaptcha'] ?>">
<input type="text" name="input_captcha" id="input_captcha" placeholder="Digite o código da imagem">
<input type="text" name="cnpj" id="cnpj" placeholder="Digite o CNPJ" value="00175318000103">
<input type="submit" value="Enviar">
<?php ActiveForm::end();?>
```

**ConsultaController.php**

```
/**
* Processa a requisição de consulta por CNPJ;
*/
public function actionProcessaCnpjSimples()
{
    try {
        $post = Yii::$app->request->post();
        if (!isset($post['cnpj']) ||
            !isset($post['input_captcha']) ||
            !isset($post['cookie']) ||
            !isset($post['viewState']) ||
            !isset($post['eventValidation']) ||
            !isset($post['hiddenField1']) ||
            !isset($post['hddServidorCaptcha'])
        )
            throw new Exception('Informe todos os campos!', 99);

        $formatter = new Formatter();
        $cnpj = $formatter->customOnlyNumberFormat($post['cnpj']);
        $return['code'] = 0;
        $return['message'] = Yii::t('app', 'Dados encontrados!');
        $resultado = ConsultaCnpjSimplesNacional::consulta(
            $cnpj,
            $post['input_captcha'],
            $post['cookie'],
            $post['viewState'],
            $post['eventValidation'],
            $post['hiddenField1'],
            $post['hddServidorCaptcha']
        );
        //$return = array_merge($return, $resultado);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $return = ['code' => $e->getCode(), 'message' => $e->getMessage()];
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($return);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

> Notem que, a estrutura atual está montada na framework **Yii2** (não achei necessário incluir ela como tag), porém ela
>   pode ser facilmente "desmontada" para implementar em qualquer outro lugar,
>   visto que o "coração" é a classe **ConsultaCnpjSimplesNacional**.

Alguém já precisou implementar uma consulta para o Simples Nacional, ou poderia indicar algum caminho do motivo de não validar as imagens (captcha) ?

Link para o [PHP Simple Html DOM Parser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/) utilizado na classe para "desfragmentar" o html e pegar os valores dos campos.

Comment: `Caracteres anti-robô inválidos. Tente novamente.` Nota-se que o mecanismo _anti-robô_ está fazendo um bom trabalho. Apenas peca por incentivar novas tentativas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alterei o código e agora utilizo o [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) para fazer as requisições e funcionou.

Segue o código atualizado da classe **ConsultaCnpjSimplesNacional.php**

```
class ConsultaCnpjSimplesNacional
{

    /**
     * Devolve um array de parâmetros para consulta de CNPJ Simples Nacional
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getParams()
    {
        $requisicao = new Client();
        $resposta = $requisicao->get('http://www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br/SimplesNacional/Aplicacoes/ATBHE/ConsultaOptantes.app/ConsultarOpcao.aspx');

        require_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'simple_html_dom.php';

        $html = str_get_html($resposta->getBody());
        $inputViewStateValue = $html->getElementById('__VIEWSTATE')->value;
        $inputEventValidationValue = $html->getElementById('__EVENTVALIDATION')->value;
        $inputHiddenField1Value = $html->getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_HiddenField1')->value;
        $inputHddServidorCaptchaValue = $html->getElementById('hddServidorCaptcha')->value;
        $urlCaptchaContainer = $html->getElementById('captcha-container')->{'data-url'};
        $html->clear();

        $resposta = $requisicao->get($urlCaptchaContainer . '/Captcha/Inicializa.ashx');

        $imgReturn = 'data:image/png;base64,' . $jsonResponse->Dados;
        return [
            'cookie' => 'captcha_token=' . $jsonResponse->Token,
            'viewState' => $inputViewStateValue,
            'eventValidation' => $inputEventValidationValue,
            'hiddenField1' => $inputHiddenField1Value,
            'hddServidorCaptcha' => $inputHddServidorCaptchaValue,
            'captchaBase64' => $imgReturn
        ];
    }

    public static function consulta($cnpj, $captcha, $stringCookie, $viewState, $eventValidation, $hiddenField, $servidorCaptcha)
    {
        $requisicao = new Client();
        $param = [
            'body' => [
                '__EVENTTARGET' => null,
                '__EVENTARGUMENT' => null,
                '__VIEWSTATE' => $viewState,
                '__EVENTVALIDATION' => $eventValidation,
                "ctl00\$ContentPlaceHolderConteudo\$$hiddenField" => $cnpj,
                'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderConteudo$HiddenField1' => $hiddenField,
                'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderConteudo$hddServidorCaptcha' => $servidorCaptcha,
                'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderConteudo$txtTexto_captcha_serpro_gov_br' => $captcha,
                'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderConteudo$btnConfirmar' => 'Consultar'
            ],
            'headers' => [
                'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
                'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate',
                'Accept-Language' => 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
                'Connection' => 'keep-alive',
                'Content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Cookie' => $stringCookie,
                'Host' => 'www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br',
                'Origin' => 'http://www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br',
                'Referer' => 'http://www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br/SimplesNacional/Aplicacoes/ATBHE/ConsultaOptantes.app/ConsultarOpcao.aspx',
                'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.152 Safari/537.36'
            ],
            'timeout' => 20, // Response timeout
            'connect_timeout' => 20, // Connection timeout
        ];
        $resposta = $requisicao->post('http://www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br/SimplesNacional/Aplicacoes/ATBHE/ConsultaOptantes.app/ConsultarOpcao.aspx', $param);

        require_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'simple_html_dom.php';

        $html = str_get_html($resposta->getBody());
        $erros = $html->getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_lblErroCaptcha');
        if (is_object($erros)) {
            $mensagemErro = 'Ocorreu algum erro, tente novamente mais tarde';
            switch (trim($erros->plaintext)) {
                case 'Caracteres anti-robô inválidos. Tente novamente.':
                    $mensagemErro = 'Erro ao consultar. Verifique se digitou corretamente o captcha.';
                    break;
                case 'O CNPJ informado deve conter 14 dígitos.':
                    $mensagemErro = 'Erro ao consultar. CNPJ deve conter 14 dígitos.';
                    break;
                case 'O CNPJ digitado é inválido.':
                    $mensagemErro = 'Erro ao consultar. CNPJ inválido.';
                    break;
            }
            throw new \Exception($mensagemErro, 99);
        }

        return [
            'cnpj' => $html->getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_lblCNPJ')->plaintext,
            'nome_empresarial' => $html->getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_lblNomeEmpresa')->plaintext,
            'situacao_simples_nacional' => $html->getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_lblSituacaoSimples')->plaintext,
            'situacao_simei' => $html->getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_lblSituacaoMei')->plaintext,
            'opcoes_pelo_simples_nacional_periodos_anteriores' => $html->getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_lblPeriodoAnterior > b > font')->plaintext,
            'opcoes_pelo_simei_periodos_anteriores' => $html->getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_lblSIMEIPeriodosAnteriores > b > font')->plaintext,
            'agendamentos_simples_nacional' => $html->getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_lblAgendamentosOpcaoSinac > b > font')->plaintext,
            'eventos_futuros_simples_nacional' => $html->getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_lblEventosFuturos > b > font')->plaintext,
            'eventos_futuros_simei' => $html->getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_lblEventosFuturosSimei > b > font')->plaintext
        ];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ao fazer a requisição do captcha, você não está obtendo a imagem associada à consulta.

Isso porque o servidor diferencia consultas diferentes pelo cookie - coisa que você não definiu. Existem duas formas de fazer isso:

1. salvando o cookie numa variável na primeira consulta, e então ao obter o captcha, você define esse mesmo cookie
2. fazendo da forma automática, utilizando um [recipiente de cookies](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR.html) antes de fazer qualquer consulta. Isso se aproxima da maneira como os navegadores lidam com os cookies.

   ```
   $filename = 'C:\pasta\cookie.txt';
   // deve conter o caminho absoluto para o arquivo

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  $filename);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $filename);
   ```

---

Esse é um problema básico que eu identifiquei olhando por cima o código. Talvez haja outros, e identificá-los é difícil, pois programar um robô com curl no PHP é antes de mais nada um trabalho de engenharia reversa.

Sugiro ativar o verbose do curl `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);` e comparar os cabeçalhos e os dados GET/POST que você envia com o que você observa na aba `Network` das `Ferramentas do Desenvolvedor` no Chrome ao fazer uma consulta manualmente (marque `Preserve log`). Se tudo estiver idêntico, vai funcionar.

Comment: Desculpe, não funcionou aparentemente, pode ser que defini da forma errada. Adicionei `curl_setopt($chInicial, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookiejar');` no primeiro cURL e `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'cookiejar',` no array de options do segundo. Vou alterar a resposta e adicionar esse código. É assim mesmo ou estou errando?

Comment: No segundo cURL, use a mesma variável `$chInicial `, basta usar `curl_setopt` para definir os parâmetros que são diferentes na segunda requisição. Atualizei a resposta com outro parâmetro que pode ser definido e outras dicas.

Comment: Continua o erro :/, vou atualizar o código...

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que o site da receita foi atualizado, nem o captcha era mais carregado e após eu ter ajustado isso, não validava mais o post dando erro invalid postback or callback validation.

Tive que informar o link completo para buscar a imagem captcha e também apssar mais informações na header no parâmetro cookie, pois além do captcha token estava sendo enviado ARRAffinity=

Segue a classe do Rafael Withoeft atualizada, pelos testes que fiz aqui tudo voltou a funcionar:

```
class ConsultaSimplesNacional {

private static function getUserAgent() {
    $agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.152 Safari/537.36';
    return isset($_SERVER['USER_AGENT']) && !empty($_SERVER['USER_AGENT']) ? $_SERVER['USER_AGENT'] : $agent;
}
/**
 * Devolve um array de parâmetros para consulta de CNPJ Simples Nacional
 * @return array
 */
public static function getParams() {
    $client = new Client();
     $param = [
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
            'Accept-Language' => 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
            'Connection' => 'keep-alive',
            'Content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Host' => 'www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br',
            'Origin' => 'http://www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br',
            'Referer' => 'http://www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br/SimplesNacional/Aplicacoes/ATBHE/ConsultaOptantes.app/ConsultarOpcao.aspx',
            'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=0',
            'Connection'=>'keep-alive',
            'Content-type'=>'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Host'=>'www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br',
            'Referer'=>'http://www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br/SimplesNacional/Aplicacoes/ATBHE/ConsultaOptantes.app/ConsultarOpcao.aspx',
            'User-Agent' => self::getUserAgent()
        ]
    ];

    $response = $client->request('GET', 'http://www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br/SimplesNacional/Aplicacoes/ATBHE/ConsultaOptantes.app/ConsultarOpcao.aspx');

    $html = str_get_html($response->getBody());
    $inputViewStateValue = $html->getElementById('__VIEWSTATE')->value;
    $viewStateGeneratorValue = $html->getElementById('__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR')->value;
    $inputHiddenField1Value = $html->getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_HiddenField1')->value;
    $inputHddServidorCaptchaValue = $html->getElementById('hddServidorCaptcha')->value;
    $urlCaptchaContainer = $html->getElementById('captcha-container')->{'data-url'};
    $html->clear();

    $response = $client->request('GET', 'http://www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br/'.$urlCaptchaContainer . '/Captcha/Inicializa.ashx');
    $cookies = $response->getHeader('Set-Cookie');
    $cookies = explode(';', $cookies[0]);
    $cookie = $cookies[0];

    $jsonResponse = json_decode($response->getBody());
    $imgReturn = 'data:image/png;base64,' . $jsonResponse->Dados;
    return [
        'cookie' => 'captcha_token=' . $jsonResponse->Token . '; '.$cookie,
        'viewState' => $inputViewStateValue,
        'hiddenField1' => $inputHiddenField1Value,
        'hddServidorCaptcha' => $inputHddServidorCaptchaValue,
        'captchaBase64' => $imgReturn
    ];
}

public static function consulta($cnpj, $captcha, $stringCookie, $viewState, $hiddenField, $servidorCaptcha) {
    $client = new Client();
    $param = [
        'form_params' => [
            '__EVENTTARGET' => null,
            '__EVENTARGUMENT' => null,
            '__VIEWSTATE' => $viewState,
            "ctl00\$ContentPlaceHolderConteudo\$$hiddenField" => $cnpj,
            'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderConteudo$HiddenField1' => $hiddenField,
            'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderConteudo$hddServidorCaptcha' => $servidorCaptcha,
            'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderConteudo$txtTexto_captcha_serpro_gov_br' => $captcha,
            'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderConteudo$btnConfirmar' => 'Consultar'
        ],
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
            'Accept-Language' => 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
            'Connection' => 'keep-alive',
            'Content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Cookie' => $stringCookie,
            'Host' => 'www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br',
            'Origin' => 'http://www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br',
            'Referer' => 'http://www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br/SimplesNacional/Aplicacoes/ATBHE/ConsultaOptantes.app/ConsultarOpcao.aspx',
            'User-Agent' => self::getUserAgent()
        ],
        'timeout' => 20, // Response timeout
        'connect_timeout' => 20, // Connection timeout
    ];
    $response = $client->request('POST', 'http://www8.receita.fazenda.gov.br/SimplesNacional/Aplicacoes/ATBHE/ConsultaOptantes.app/ConsultarOpcao.aspx', $param);

    $html = str_get_html($response->getBody());
    $erros = $html->getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_lblErroCaptcha');
    if (is_object($erros)) {
        $mensagemErro = 'Ocorreu algum erro, tente novamente mais tarde';
        switch (utf8_decode($erros->plaintext)) {
            case 'Caracteres anti-robô inválidos. Tente novamente.':
                $mensagemErro = 'Erro ao consultar. Verifique se digitou corretamente o captcha.';
                break;
            case 'O CNPJ informado deve conter 14 dígitos.':
                $mensagemErro = 'Erro ao consultar. CNPJ deve conter 14 dígitos.';
                break;
            case 'O CNPJ digitado é inválido.':
                $mensagemErro = 'Erro ao consultar. CNPJ inválido.';
                break;
        }
        throw new \Exception($mensagemErro, 99);
    }

    return [
        'cnpj' => trim(utf8_decode($html->getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_lblCNPJ')->plaintext)),
        'nome_empresarial' => trim(utf8_decode($html->getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_lblNomeEmpresa')->plaintext)),
        'situacao_simples_nacional' => trim(utf8_decode($html->getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_lblSituacaoSimples')->plaintext)),
        'situacao_simei' => trim(utf8_decode($html->getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_lblSituacaoMei')->plaintext)),
        'opcoes_pelo_simples_nacional_periodos_anteriores' => trim(utf8_decode($html->getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_lblPeriodoAnterior > b > font')->plaintext)),
        'opcoes_pelo_simei_periodos_anteriores' => trim(utf8_decode($html->getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_lblSIMEIPeriodosAnteriores > b > font')->plaintext)),
        'agendamentos_simples_nacional' => trim(utf8_decode($html->getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_lblAgendamentosOpcaoSinac > b > font')->plaintext)),
        'eventos_futuros_simples_nacional' => trim(utf8_decode($html->getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_lblEventosFuturos > b > font')->plaintext)),
        'eventos_futuros_simei' => trim(utf8_decode($html->getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderConteudo_lblEventosFuturosSimei > b > font')->plaintext))
    ];
}
```

}

Comment: Boa tarde, realmente, houveram alterações no site do simples nacional... agradeço sua contribuição :). Internamente, aqui na empresa, já havíamos corrigido essa situação, mas não disponibilizamos na internet a solução atualizada...., Qualquer dúvida estou a disposição.

Comment: Removeram o campo __EVENTVALIDATION do site, tive que atualizar novamente a classe pois como não está mais no HTML dava erro.